# Combine Matlab figures containing subplots

Tags: matlab

is there a way to combine two already saved Matlab figures both with a 1x3 grid of subplots, into one new figure with a 2x3 grid of subplots. The axis limits and labels should not be altered. All graphs are scatterplots with fit functions.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't know if there is a quick way. But you can always load this figures, get everything you need (data,labels, etc..) using `get` function and plot data like you want on a new figure. I can post the answer how do it, if this method is ok for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the functions `openfig` with the option 'invisible' to open the saved figure, get the axes with `get` and then use the `copyobj` function to copy the axes in the new subplot.